# Designing a Core Data model to remember previous object states

Tags: ios, design-patterns, core-data, database-design

Let's say we have a simple Core Data model which keeps track of transactions a bunch customer makes, but for some reason, when we look at transactions, we want to know the customers address at the time the transaction was made.

If the customer changes their address, what is the best way to store the old state of the customer?

[image: Data model design]

One way might be to store the customer's address on the transaction, but that wouldn't work with to-many relationships, e.g. if prices of multiple products in a previous transaction changed, how would we record that?

Another option would be to just duplicate the objects, but then we need some way of knowing which is the current one. Would It be better to create intermediary entities which are related to both the transaction and the customer/product?

Comment: I think save the ``address`` in transaction is the correct way, i don't see your point. Usually a transaction is related to a concrete address, the customer could have multiple address and the transaction still should be related to one address.

Comment: @Gonzalo sure, but what about the product price example, where there are multiple products?

Comment: So, your real problem is the product price, because address can be resolved like that. In a relational model you could save every change to products like an historic and the transaction will reference to the historic. I haven't done anything like this but what comes to my mind is to make the transactions in a no relational model.

Comment: @Gonzalo can you provide some more detail in an answer?

Answer (score 1):

From your description I'd probably do this:

[image: Data model]

- Every `Customer` has an `Address`.
- Every `Transaction` has an `Address`.
- If the `Customer` gets a new `Address`, this doesn't affect any existing `Transaction`'s `Address`.
- You can always find all transactions for an address, or the address for any transaction, even if the customer address changes.
- If necessary you can get all addresses for a customer by looking at the customer's transactions, and getting the addresses for those. You could also add a `pastAddresses` relationship from `Customer` to `Address` if you need it.

Comment: This is kind of what I was leaning towards. But what about the case of a product’s price changing? Would you create something like an ProductOrder entity which stores the price and quantity with a relationship to the product, and just have a list of those objects on the transaction?